# Gatling Test suite Java

Tags: java, testing, gatling, assertion, suite

We run our test in Jenkins from package where we have 10 classes. Each class represents one scenario.

At the end we have one graph trend where we have trends for all tests.
But when we try to add assertion and assertion failed, the build failed too.

test run command:

```java
mvn gatling:test -D gatling.includes=packageName.*
```

Is it possible to made test suite where each scenario have own assertion, not in setup?

Is it possible to made build fail after finishing all tests, even if the assertion for some test failed and after that in Jenkins getting tests trends in one graph (in one graph 10 tests trends)?

Comment: Can you show some example code? I have a hard time imagining your project structure

Answer (score 0):

No. Assertions are currently only global, not per scenario.